# Azure Worker Role generating writing unexpected error to Trace log storage

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

We have a worker role running in the cloud which polls an Azure CloudQueue periodically retrieving messages that a web role has put on there for us.  Currently the worker role and web role are housed in the same Cloud Service application and currently we are only running one instance.

As we are testing we have our logging switched on and so the contents of the messages and other useful information appear in our cloud storage which we view using Cerebrata Azure Diagnostics Manager. (Great product btw)

DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

diagConfig.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;

It all appears to work remarkably well actually, however occasionally we see a Verbose message in the trace log which simply has "Fail"as the message.  The code it appears to be generated from is wrapped in a try catch so it is odd that we aren't seeing the message through those means.

It would appear that something is happening that is out of our code's control, perhaps the worker role is being restarted, or the cloud op system is detecting a major error that only it can deal with by restarting our worker role.  It recovers and carries on so it is somewhat of a mystery to us what might be happening.

What we haven't ascertained yet is whether we are losing a message.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.
Cheers
Kindo Malay

Answer (score 0):

Without the stack trace it's hard to say too much, but with the logging set to verbose it's quite likely that you're seeing some internal logging from one of the dlls you're using.

For example if you run a Azure Table query that causes certain kinds of errors, the error will be logged out 3 times because the storage client library is catching the error, tracing it out and then retrying.

If the error is not being caught by your try catch block, then it's likely nothing you need to worry about.

If deliverability of queue messages is important to you, you should ensure that you make use of the visibility timeout overload of CloudQueue.GetMessage and only delete the message when you've finished processing it.  You may end up processing some messages twice, but at least you will process all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If your role instance is getting restarted after running for a while, it's often because your process exited due to an unhandled exception.

Comment: Sorry for not replying and thanking to the people who took the time to answer this question, we've not solved it but have made some progress.  Thnks again!